# iOS-like Android UI library

Tags: android, user-interface

I would like know:

1) If there is any Android UI library that looks just like the iPhone UI?

2) If there isn't any, I am planning on creating one as an open source project. Will I get sued by Apple?

Thanks,

Comment: Apple loves to sue everyone, so I'd say yes on 2

Comment: I don't know. But I hope nobody is going to use it... since we don't want iOS ux in Android.

Comment: I think you get more than Apple in Android. So why are you wasting your effort?

Comment: Follow the Android Designer Guidelines instead of bothering with iOS stuff. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html

Comment: StackOverflow is not a law office. Please contact qualified legal counsel for your "Will I get sued by Apple?" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only Library I know is this one: 
https://github.com/thiagolocatelli/android-uitableview
Its a copy of the UITableView from iOS (Like the IOS-version of a ListView).

To your other question:
I dont think that apple would sue someone for creating an open source library. They yould sue the Open source alliance for implementing it in android though.